# Is there any method to differentiate two Linux machines with the same MAC address?

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

In Linux, it's possible to override your MAC address. Is there any way to differentiate two machines by a processor serial number or some other unique identifier, available in user space? The two machines would probably be virtually identical in configuration otherwise - same CPU, same memory, same manufacturer etc

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to differentiate two machines by a processor serial number or some other unique identifier, available in user space?

The answer is **no**. And think of an important aspect: the kernel is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software). If it is outputting a serial id (like `0123456789`) in some way (to user-land, and that means thru some of the [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)) and if I know that your application is expecting that id on computer A, I could hack my kernel running on computer B to output exactly that `0123456789` in the same situation.

In other words, not only the answer is no, but any clever Linux user (capable of changing a few lines in the kernel source code) could hack and recompile his kernel to produce the same effect as you want it to be.

So you need to give up your silly dreams or to give up targetting Linux.

Read about [Trusted Computing Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_computing_base) and [Hardware Security Module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module) (you might require one, and provide such a hardware to your customers; it could be as cheap as some [smart card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_card)). That HSM is some *active* hardware device which might behave as follow: your application sends some random `12865` number, it gets back some `89621` number from the HSM so is able to check that the HSM is a genuine one (because the computation in the HSM matches the computation in your application) using some kind of [public-key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography).

Perhaps you want some way of authentifying usability of your software. You could buy and use some [software license server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_license_server).

In practice, in professional sittings (e.g. all corporations) that might not be very useful. There is a social reason for that: a (non-tiny) corporation X has employees. They could quit. Then they could write to some authority (or software provider) about X not respecting software licenses. That could either entails some legal prosecutions (which are costly to corporations) or some huge fine against corporation X, or a very bad reputation for X (for instance, qualified persons won't want to work for X). Such social reasons are enough for companies to be serious about software licenses. So technical means to enforce software licenses are not very useful (the legal and social mean is often enough).

Comment: I'm not expecting something foolproof. An application I support uses a license manager that keys off of Hardware MAC address, and I suspect someone is trying to spoof the license manager by running multiple copies of the same server and switching them somehow. I think modifying the kernel is beyond them, but modifying the MAC address is relatively easy and is the "known" method by which the license manager is operating.

Comment: If you modify something else than MAC, that something else will rapidly be as easy to modify as the MAC.

Comment: And if I find out what to modify and publish a patch to the kernel so that it follows the passive behavior expected by your application, you probably cannot prosecute me for such a patch. So you are screwed. "security by obscurity" don't work well

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that there is, but the details would likely be very brand- and model-specific. For example, I have a Dell laptop in my office that has a serial number on its baseboard (and also serial numbers on various other components).

Run `sudo dmidecode` and look for "Serial Number":

```
[snip]
Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
        Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
        Product Name: Latitude E5440
        Version: 01
        Serial Number: 1CWHVZ1
```

It is common for server boxes to have serial numbers like this as well. I don't know how well standardized the layout is.

The network interface also often has a "permanent" (burned-in) MAC address that is not so easy to change. Again, on my Dell laptop:

```
sudo ethtool -P eno1
Permanent address: ec:f4:bb:03:67:2f
```

Comment: Correct, but see my answer. If I know that some software expects exactly a serial number `1CWHVZ1` I could quite easily patch the kernel running on my Linux box to send that number. So what is really useful is some active *hardware* device with which the application is *interacting*. That is called a hardware security module

Comment: @Basile your argument is technically correct, but this is about raising the bar. If it's easy to do something like dup a MAC address and one can do it with readily available tools, that's one thing. Patching kernels (or even installing a custom kernel *you* create for them) is beyond the resources of the typical user, and would likely be seen as more trouble than it's worth. And anyway what's to stop me from disassembling your HSM code and bypassing that interaction. Sure, that's hard (and it's possible to make it harder still). The question is how high does the bar actually need to be?

Comment: Good analysis. But look also at my "social & legal" arguments. In the current world, you probably don't *practically* even need *any* technical means to enforce software licenses.